# Error copying files in Linux shell bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm try to copy files from a location (/home/ppaa/workspace/partial/medium) to another location (/home/ppaa/workspace/complete) using bash shell scripting in Linux.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash -u

MY_BASE_FOLDER='/home/ppaa/workspace/'
MY_TARGET_FOLDER='/home/ppaa/workspace/complete/'
cp $MY_BASE_FOLDER'partial/medium/*.*' $MY_TARGET_FOLDER
return=$?
echo "return: $return"
```

The folders exists and the files are copied but the value of return variable is 1. Whats wrong?

Comment: `cp` returns error code 0 on success and 1 on failure.

Comment: I know, but the copy is successful.

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that the copy was *not* (completely) successful.  `cp` will exit with non-zero status if it is unable to copy *any* of the specified files.  That could happen for any number of reasons, but one reasonably likely one is that your source glob matches one or more directories.  Non-recursive `cp` will not copy directories, and will exit with status 1 if asked to do so.  It will still copy the files it can, however.

Comment: agree with above. And just to confirm an unmentioned bit of information ... Are there any error messages reported i.e. `cp: none-such : not found`. OR are you redirecting std-err to `/dev/null` someplace you are not showing us? i.e. `.... 2> /dev/null` . Good luck.

Comment: Tried running "cp --verbose" ?

Answer (score 2):

The files are not copied. `cp` is most likely giving you an error like:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/ppaa/workspace/partial/medium/*.*’: No such file or directory
```

This is because globs (like `*.*`) are not expanded in quotes. Instead, use:

```
cp "$MY_BASE_FOLDER/partial/medium"/*.* "$MY_TARGET_FOLDER"
```

Comment: I would like to add that if you are your setting variables existence checks before execution (i.e check x first `${x:?}`) do not use quote at all. Like this `cp ${x:?} ${y:?}`. Putting quotes around both x and y will cause the same error.